# Запятая после "ох"

Tags: запятые, части-речи, частица, междометие

Открываем [Грамоту](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D1%85&all=x):

**ОХ, *межд.***
<...>
**2.** Выражает восхищение, удивление, и т.п. *Ох, хороша! Ох и ягод в лесу сколько!* // Усиливает значение слова, к которому примыкает. *Ох, плохо мне! Ох, как здорово. Ох и обманываешь ты меня. Ох, какая плохая погода!*

Неужели во всех примерах действительно нужны запятые, где они есть? А мне кажется, что нужны они, только если *ох* произносится восклицательно и есть пауза после него, а в других случаях, я думаю, оно может быть частицей, как в случае с *ну.* Она тут больше подходит, чаще так скажешь. Почему-то Грамота вообще не рассматривает *ох* как частицу, только как междометие. *Разве наше "ох" не может быть ею?*

Comment: «Ох» вполне может быть частицей. И бывает. А вы-то сами почему рассматриваете только «ох», пренебрегая «ах», «ой» и «ай»?

Comment: Я не пренебрегаю, просто открыл страницу именно про это слово.

Comment: А, понятно. И я не придираюсь, просто у меня на памяти, как на одном форуме с лингвистическим уклоном я усомнился, что Ильфу и Петрову действительно следовало обособить запятыми «ах» в одном их фельетоне: в данной фразе «ах» явно частица, а не междометие. И со мной согласились.

Comment: Розенталь в параграфе про междометия ссылается на: *Шведова Н. Ю. Очерки по синтаксису русской разговорной речи. М., 1960. С. 252—269 (оттуда заимствованы и некоторые примеры)*.

Answer (score 3):

Наткнулся на следующее, решил скинуть.

Розенталь:
Не отделяются запятой от некоторых местоимений и частиц междометия *ах, ох, ух, эх, ай, ой, эк*, образующие **цельные сочетания с этими местоимениями** (*ах ты, ах вы, ух ты, эх ты, ох эти*) **или частицами** (*ай да, ох и, эх и, эй и, ух и*), например: *Ах я дурак! Ах ты проклятый! Ах ты умница моя! Ах он змея! Ах она старая чертовка! Ах они мошенники этакие! Ах ты грех какой! Эх ты жизнь! Ух ты! Ох эти кумушки! Ах эта тетушка! Эх эти мальчишки! Ох уж эти мне переезды! Эх и песня! Ох и ездок! Ух и вино! Ой и свидетель! Ох и жмет! Ох и вкусно! Ох и печет же сегодня! Эх и придумал! Эх и ударили! Эх и рассердился! Ох и надоело же! Ох и хлебнул же он горя в жизни! Эк ты храпишь! Эк он обрадовался! Эк какую цену завернули! Ох и устал же я! Ай да молодец наш Коля! Ай да мед!* (Пушкин). *Ай да Солоха!* (Гоголь). В подобных случаях значение эмоции выражается не одним междометием, а всей конструкцией; ср.: *Ух бедная! Ух что сделаю! Староста наш — эх башка! Ай Моська!*
Указанные междометия входят как составной элемент в некоторые предложения с повторяющимися словами, например: *Хорошо здесь, ах хорошо! Трудно, ох трудно! Тонкий расчет у командира, ох тонкий! Нудный ты, ух нудный! Достанется тебе от матери, ух достанется! Хочется мне тебе всыпать, ой хочется.*

То есть у Розенталя это междометия (не частицы), способные образовывать цельные сочетания (без запятой). Этим правилом объясняется отсутствие запятой после "ох и" в примерах словаря.

Comment: ***Интересно!***

Answer (score 2):

Слишком сложный и слишком обширный вопрос. В качестве ответа-комментария сошлюсь на Н.Ю. Шведову в поддержку Вашей точки зрения (см. вторую колонку на стр. 322 [здесь](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/razgranichenie-chastits-i-mezhdometiy-v-predlozhenii-vyskazyvanii/viewer); статья написана скорее для уровня школьного преподавания). На более сложном уровне проблематика поднимается [здесь](http://www.dialog-21.ru/media/1807/87.pdf) — и тут уже очевидно, что у данного вопроса не предвидится простого и однозначного решения.

Comment: Спасибо большое, grizzly! Потом дома с компьютера гляну. Рад, что меня поддерживает какая-то Шведова.))

Comment: Надеюсь, Вы шутите? В моём представлении мнение "какой-то" Шведовой даже более авторитетно, чем мнение Розенталя, например :)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Есть же толковый словарь Ожегова и Шведовой. Составители словарей как бы самые умные.

Comment: Мне стыдно, но я её не знал. :)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой И про словарь такой ни разу не слышал? Не верю.

Comment: Может, и слышал, но не вдумывался.

Answer (score 2):

Цитата:  ***С примерами-то что, Шарон?***

Итак, Артем,  ваш комментарий не оставил мне шанса уйти от ответа :))
Поэтому я познакомлю вас с моими «исследованиями»  по этой теме.

1. ОХ и АХ ничем не отличаются друг от друга, это – **междометия, а не частицы**. Хотя Розенталь  и  называет подобные слова и частицами, и междометиями, но то же Розенталь! К тому же это справочник по правописанию, а не грамматика.
2. В грамматике все  не так, там **частицы – это служебные слова с различными функциями**, а частиц АХ и ОХ даже в перечне эмоционально-экспрессивных частиц  нет, там такие варианты: *ведь, как, ну и, страсть, то-то* и др. Правда, вот междометие О как-то сюда «записалось».
3. **Междометия могут соединяться** с различными словами – вот тогда они образуют междометные сочетания, которые пишутся **без запятой**.

Причем  они весьма неразборчивы в своих связях и с чем только не сочетаются, например:  с различными союзами, со знаменательными словами, с обращениями, со словами ДА и НЕТ, с местоимениями. Особенно любят повторяющиеся слов, так к ним  и липнут.

4. А это примеры из Розенталя  (остальные уже приводились):

**О поле, поле!** Кто тебя усеял мёртвыми костями? (П.)

**Ну как** не порадеть родному человечку! (Гр.)

**Ой ты гой еси,** Волга, мать родная! (П.)

**Ах ты**, обжора! (Кр.)

Спасибо за внимание, больше вроде бы сказать нечего :))

Comment: *но то же Розенталь!* — а Шведова? Ведь у неё работы по грамматике, а не по правописанию. Шведова говорит, что "Ох эти кумушки" равнозначно "Уж эти кумушки". Этот Ваш ответ мне нравится больше, чем прошлый, поскольку Вы уже осознали, что всё не так просто, как показалось сначала. Но я думаю, что этот ответ в чём-то противоречит предыдущему и надеюсь, что со временем появится третий — интегральный, а лишние тогда уже можно будет удалить.

Comment: Ну да,  частично осознала,  в этом вы правы, но не уверена, что готова углубиться в эту тему.  К тому же она явно излагается на разных уровнях: научном, вузовском и школьно-потребительском.  А интересы в этом случае разные: это или приблизительное знакомство с практической темой, или материал для специальной научной лингвистики. Я, конечно, не против и всё удалить :)), но с другой стороны сам процесс постижение истины (заблуждений, открытий и пр.)  также по-своему  поучителен.

Comment: Спасибо, Шарон, только я спрашивал про примеры Грамоты из первой половины моего вопроса.

Comment: Пожалуйста, Артем, но в мое толкование подойдут любые фразы. Самостоятельны и отделены запятой только междометия (или еще составные междометные сочетания).  Если же междометие соединилось с любым словом, то оно стало усилительной частицей. Мы видим, что оба слова ведут себя одинаково.

Comment: Я спросил, Грамота права в том, что "ох" обособлено в большинстве примеров, или нет. Смотрите примеры из моего вопроса.

Comment: Смотрю примеры из Грамоты, добавляю еще несколько из Нацкорпуса. И вижу: все определяется структурой и фонетикой.  Если без паузы не прочитаешь, то это междометие.  В других случаях оба варианта подходят, например: Ох,  как хорошО  и ох как хорошО! Вот и вся грамматика. Теория сложная, а практика простая, никаких особых загадок. Просто читайте так, как читается удобно.

Comment: Спасибо, Шарон, я так же рассуждал (что можно по-разному читать). Но в некоторых случаях с запятой больше подходит частица и убрать запятую, imho.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Это не Грамота, а толковый словарь Кузнецова.

Comment: @oleedd: примеры в любом случае на Грамоте.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Это да, но "*Почему-то Грамота вообще не рассматривает*" явно перебор.

Comment: @oleedd: да я не разбираюсь, какие там где словари.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Клацаешь на зелёную ссылку над текстом и читаешь.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Междометия и частицы**

Междометия отличаются от частиц в соответствии с определением,  то  есть  по  смыслу  и по интонации.

**Междометия**  выражают чувства, не называя их;  они выделяются паузой в устной речи, а на письме запятой (или восклицательным знаком).

**Частицы**  **относятся (примыкают)  к различным частям речи:** они усиливают эмоциональность сообщения, произносятся без паузы и ударения и не выделяются на письме запятой.

**2. Примеры с частицей ОХ:**

Достанется тебе, ох достанется! Живётся ему ох как несладко! Ох и жарко сегодня! Ох мне эти обеды!  (Н.В. Гоголь). Я вечор, ох я гуляла, грусть хотела разогнать…

Ох ты зверь, ты зверина, Ты скажи своё имя. (Частица примыкает к обращению).

Возможно, эта частица встречается  реже других, но в остальном она мало чем от них отличается.

**Примечание** (добавим немного академичности)

Речь идет о **парных вариантах** частиц и междометий. По классификации 1980 года частицы относятся к служебным словам, а междометия  существуют сами по себе (они не знаменательные и не служебные).

Разумеется, частицы – это сложный класс слов со своей классификацией, но здесь мы рассматриваем эмоционально-экспрессивную группу частиц, не оказывающих значительного влияния на основную семантику, но имеющих эмоционально-оценочное значение.

Comment: Грамота же неправа?

Comment: А что не так с Грамотой, Артем? Если смотреть в словаре Кузнецова статьи для слов"ах" и "ох", то они очень похожи, только ОХ не названа частицей,  а значение усиления указано для обоих слов.  В Нацкорпусе  вы также при желании можете найти совершенно  одинаковые конструкции для ОХ, АХ и всех похожих слов.

Comment: *только ОХ не названа частицей* — думаю, что не зря так, "ах" гораздо сильнее примыкает в примерах.

Comment: Как же вы объясните этот совершенно уникальный факт? И точно ли он имеет место?  Здесь, вероятно,  нужны специалисты по фонетике с точными приборами :)

Comment: *с точными приборами* — ))), можно и без этого. Заметил три типа примыкания: слабое, среднее и сильное. Так вот при слабом ставят запятую, при среднем — уже нет, а при сильном — уже считают частицей.

Comment: Где не ставят запятую, там и примыкания нет - вот и все решение вопроса. А таких вариантов достаточно.  Так что обычная это частицы, чуть менее частотная и все. Фирма гарантирует :))

Comment: Что за примыкание? Примеры с Грамоты в моём вопросе.

Comment: Примыкание — это про паузу после междометия. Sharon, да наоборот, где не ставят запятую, там как раз есть примыкание — тесно примыкает к следующему слову. А вот частицы прямо сливаются с ним — максимальное примыкание.

Comment: Ну да, я так и понял, только возник вопрос, потому что действительно вроде наоборот.

Comment: @oleedd  Еще главное забыли – на частицу ударение не падает
Дл справок: ПРОКЛИТИКА (от греч. «procliticon» - наклоняющийся вперёд) – безударное слово, примыкающее к следующему за ним ударному, составляя с ним одну стопу. Чаще всего проклитику в русском языке образуют служебные части речи (ЧАСТИЦЫ, предлоги, союзы).

Comment: С примерами-то что, Шарон?